# How can I pass value through process variable in Camunda to subflow from main flow

Tags: camunda

Colleagues,

Can you please advise me a bit about the following.

I cannot figure out how to pass value through process variable from main flow to its subflow in Camunda. I am putting value to process variable in one task in main flow via execution.setVariable("toolId", toolId);
where execution is an instance of DelegateExecution. I am trying to retrieve in another task of subflow via
Long toolId = (Long) execution.getVariable("toolId");
However I am getting null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By *subflow* I assume you mean a call activity (otherwise the data would be available).

A call activity references a technically independent process instance with its own data. Therefore you have to explicitly map the in data, which should be copied from the source (parent) to the target (sub process) and also the out data in the other direction.

Please see: https://docs.camunda.io/docs/components/modeler/bpmn/call-activities/#variable-mappings and https://docs.camunda.io/docs/components/concepts/variables/#inputoutput-variable-mappings

Comment: You are right, I meant call activity by the subflow. In mapping of the variable toolId in the Call Activity helped. I did it before, but without any success. Probably made some mistake. Thank you very much. Now I can go on with my project.